# Makefile for compiling a number of .cpp and .h into a lib

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, cygwin, compilation

I am running Windows 7 with gcc/g++ under Cygwin. What would be the Makefile format (and extension, I think it's .mk?) for compiling a set of .cpp (C++ source) and .h (header) files into a static library (.dll). Say I have a variable set of files:

- file1.cpp
- file1.h
- file2.cpp
- file2.h
- file3.cpp
- file3.h
- ....

What would be the makefile format (and extension) for compiling these into a static library? (I'm very new to makefiles) What would be the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension would be none at all, and the file is called `Makefile` (or `makefile`) if you want GNU Make to find it automatically.

GNU Make, at least, lets you rely on certain automatic variables that alone give you control over much of the building process with C/C++ files as input. These variables include `CC`, `CPP`, `CFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS`, `CXX`, `CXXFLAGS`, and `LDFLAGS`. These control the switches to the C/C++ preprocessor, compiler, and the linker (the program that in the end assembles your program) that `make` will use.

GNU Make also includes a lot of implicit rules designed to enable it automatically build programs from C/C++ source code, so you don't [always] have to write your own rules.

For instance, even *without* a makefile, if you try to run `make foobar`, GNU Make will attempt to first build `foobar.o` from `foobar.c` or `foobar.cpp` if it finds either, by invoking appropriate compiler, and then will attempt to build `foobar` by assembling (incl. linking) its parts from system libraries and `foobar.o`. In short, GNU Make knows how to build the `foobar` program even without a makefile being present -- thanks to implicit rules. You can see these rules by invoking `make` with the `-p` switch.

Some people like to rely on GNU Make's implicit rule database to have lean and short makefiles where only that specific to their project is specified, while some people may go as far as to disable the entire implicit rule database (using the `-r` switch) and have full control of the building process by specifying everything in their makefile(s). I won't comment on superiority of either strategy, rest assured both do work to some degree.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of options you can set when building a dll, but here's a basic command that you could use if you were doing it from the command line:

```
gcc -shared -o mydll.dll file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

And here's a makefile (typically called `Makefile`) that will handle the whole build process:

```
# You will have to modify this line to list the actual files you use.
# You could set it to use all the "fileN" files that you have,
# but that's dangerous for a beginner.
FILES = file1 file2 file3

OBJECTS = $(addsuffix .o,$(FILES)) # This is "file1.o file2.o..."

# This is the rule it uses to assemble file1.o, file2.o... into mydll.dll
mydll.dll: $(OBJECTS)
    gcc -shared $^ -o $@    # The whitespace at the beginning of this line is a TAB.

# This is the rule it uses to compile fileN.cpp and fileN.h into fileN.o
$(OBJECTS): %.o : %.cpp %.h
    g++ -c $< -o $@         # Again, a TAB at the beginning.
```

Now to build `mydll.dll`, just type "make".

A couple of notes. If you just type "make" without specifying the makefile or the target (the thing to be built), Make will try to use the default makefile ("GNUMakefile", "makefile" or "Makefile") and the default target (the first one in the makefile, in this case `mydll.dll`).